# how to query in codeigniter database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $where = "(rank = '2')"; 
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from('deceased');
    $this->db->join('causes', 'causes.id = deceased.id');
```

i have a query from codeigniter, and i should get the rank 2, but the problem is, if there is no rank 2 i should get the rank 1.

db_deceased (id primary key)

`id   date_died
 1   2014-01-01
 2   2014-03-19`

db_causes (id foreign key)

```
id  cause   rank
1   J96.0    1
1   J44.1    2
2   I21      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should try with `$this->db->or_where();` either `$this->db->or_where_in();` but also consider documentation's approach writing arguments there. Your $where variable should be like `$where = array('name =' => '2');`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('name =', '2');
$this->db->or_where('name =', '1');
$this->db->from('deceased');
$this->db->join('causes', 'causes.id = deceased.id');
```

Active records are pretty well explained in [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: I agree with Tpojka. The main problem you're facing is that you need to pass an array to the `$this->db->where()` instance.